# Virtualbox on Intel Mac Mini does not detect VT-x

Tags: virtualization, cpu, virtualbox

I am running `VirtualBox VM 7.0.12 r159484 darwin.amd64 (Oct 12 2023 20:27:35)` on Intel Mac Mini:

```
Model Name: Mac mini
Model Identifier: Macmini8,1
Processor Name: 6-Core Intel Core i5
Processor Speed: 3 GHz
Number of Processors: 1
Total Number of Cores: 6
L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
L3 Cache: 9 MB
Memory: 8 GB
System Firmware Version: 1968.140.7.0.0 (iBridge: 20.16.6072.0.0,0)
OS Loader Version: 577.140.2~15
```

VirtualBox does not detect CPU virtualization extensions (VT-x) and the guest (32-bit Win XP) runs terribly slow.

I think this is the relevant part of `VBox.log`:

```
00:00:00.322003 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_capability.
00:00:00.322015 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vm_space_create.
00:00:00.322019 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vm_space_destroy.
00:00:00.322024 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vm_map_space.
00:00:00.322028 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vm_unmap_space.
00:00:00.322031 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vm_protect_space.
00:00:00.322036 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vcpu_set_space.
00:00:00.322043 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vcpu_run_until.
00:00:00.322047 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vcpu_get_exec_time.
00:00:00.322052 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vmx_vcpu_read_shadow_vmcs.
00:00:00.322056 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vmx_vcpu_write_shadow_vmcs.
00:00:00.322059 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vmx_vcpu_set_shadow_access.
00:00:00.322063 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vmx_get_msr_info.
00:00:00.322067 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vmx_vcpu_get_cap_write_vmcs.
00:00:00.322070 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vcpu_enable_managed_msr.
00:00:00.322074 NEM:  info: Found optional import Hypervisor!hv_vcpu_set_msr_access.
00:00:00.322102 NEM: cMachTimePerNs=1 (TimeInfo.numer=1 TimeInfo.denom=1)
00:00:00.323768 NEM: Successfully created ASID: 1
00:00:00.323877 NEM:
00:00:00.323877 NEM: NEMR3Init: Turtle execution mode is active!
00:00:00.323878 NEM: Note! VirtualBox is not able to run at its full potential in this execution mode.
00:00:00.323878 NEM:
00:00:00.323968 CPUM: No hardware-virtualization capability detected
00:00:00.324437 CPUM: fXStateHostMask=0x7; initial: 0x7; host XCR0=0x7
00:00:00.325550 CPUM: Matched host CPU INTEL 0x6/0x9e/0xa Intel_Core7_CoffeeLake with CPU DB entry 'Intel Core i7-6700K' (INTEL 0x6/0x5e/0x3 Intel_Core7_Skylake)
00:00:00.325817 CPUM: MXCSR_MASK=0xffff (host: 0xffff)
00:00:00.325863 CPUM: Failed to query microcode revision. rc=VERR_SUP_DRIVERLESS
00:00:00.325923 CPUM: Changing leaf 13[0]: EBX=0x340 -> 0x340, ECX=0x440 -> 0x340
00:00:00.325989 CPUM: MSR/CPUID reconciliation insert: 0x0000010b IA32_FLUSH_CMD
00:00:00.325995 CPUM: MSR/CPUID reconciliation insert: 0x0000010a IA32_ARCH_CAPABILITIES
00:00:00.326000 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x00000001 IA32_P5_MC_TYPE
00:00:00.326004 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x00000017 IA32_PLATFORM_ID
00:00:00.326007 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x0000001b IA32_APIC_BASE
00:00:00.326011 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x0000008b BIOS_SIGN
00:00:00.326014 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x000000fe IA32_MTRRCAP
00:00:00.326018 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x00000179 IA32_MCG_CAP
00:00:00.326021 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x0000017a IA32_MCG_STATUS
00:00:00.326024 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x000001a0 IA32_MISC_ENABLE
00:00:00.326028 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x000001d9 IA32_DEBUGCTL
00:00:00.326031 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x000001db P6_LAST_BRANCH_FROM_IP
00:00:00.326034 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x000001dc P6_LAST_BRANCH_TO_IP
00:00:00.326038 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x000001dd P6_LAST_INT_FROM_IP
00:00:00.326041 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x000001de P6_LAST_INT_TO_IP
00:00:00.326044 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x00000277 IA32_PAT
00:00:00.326048 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x000002ff IA32_MTRR_DEF_TYPE
00:00:00.326051 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x00000400 IA32_MCi_CTL_STATUS_ADDR_MISC
00:00:00.326069 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0xc0000103 AMD64_TSC_AUX
00:00:00.326073 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x00000122 IA32_TSX_CTRL
00:00:00.326131 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled PAE
00:00:00.326242 NEM:    VMX_VMCS32_CTRL_PIN_EXEC = (allowed_0=0x00003f allowed_1=0x00007f)
00:00:00.326251 NEM:        Bit 00 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326255 NEM:        Bit 01 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326258 NEM:        Bit 02 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326261 NEM:        Bit 03 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326264 NEM:        Bit 04 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326268 NEM:        Bit 05 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326271 NEM:        Bit 06 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326274 NEM:        Bit 07 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326277 NEM:        Bit 08 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326281 NEM:        Bit 09 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326284 NEM:        Bit 10 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326287 NEM:        Bit 11 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326290 NEM:        Bit 12 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326293 NEM:        Bit 13 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326297 NEM:        Bit 14 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326300 NEM:        Bit 15 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326303 NEM:        Bit 16 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326306 NEM:        Bit 17 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326309 NEM:        Bit 18 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326313 NEM:        Bit 19 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326316 NEM:        Bit 20 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326319 NEM:        Bit 21 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326322 NEM:        Bit 22 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326325 NEM:        Bit 23 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326329 NEM:        Bit 24 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326332 NEM:        Bit 25 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326335 NEM:        Bit 26 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326338 NEM:        Bit 27 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326341 NEM:        Bit 28 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326345 NEM:        Bit 29 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326348 NEM:        Bit 30 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326351 NEM:        Bit 31 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326355 NEM:    VMX_VMCS32_CTRL_PROC_EXEC = (allowed_0=0x9500697a allowed_1=0xfdf9fffe)
00:00:00.326359 NEM:        Bit 00 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326362 NEM:        Bit 01 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326365 NEM:        Bit 02 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326368 NEM:        Bit 03 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326372 NEM:        Bit 04 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326375 NEM:        Bit 05 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326378 NEM:        Bit 06 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326381 NEM:        Bit 07 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326384 NEM:        Bit 08 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326387 NEM:        Bit 09 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326391 NEM:        Bit 10 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326394 NEM:        Bit 11 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326397 NEM:        Bit 12 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326400 NEM:        Bit 13 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326404 NEM:        Bit 14 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326407 NEM:        Bit 15 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326410 NEM:        Bit 16 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326413 NEM:        Bit 17 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326416 NEM:        Bit 18 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326420 NEM:        Bit 19 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326423 NEM:        Bit 20 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326426 NEM:        Bit 21 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326429 NEM:        Bit 22 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326432 NEM:        Bit 23 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326435 NEM:        Bit 24 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326439 NEM:        Bit 25 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326442 NEM:        Bit 26 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326445 NEM:        Bit 27 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326448 NEM:        Bit 28 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326451 NEM:        Bit 29 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326455 NEM:        Bit 30 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326458 NEM:        Bit 31 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326461 NEM:    VMX_VMCS32_CTRL_EXCEPTION_BITMAP = (allowed_0=0x000000 allowed_1=0xffffffff)
00:00:00.326465 NEM:        Bit 00 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326468 NEM:        Bit 01 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326481 NEM:        Bit 02 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326484 NEM:        Bit 03 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326488 NEM:        Bit 04 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326491 NEM:        Bit 05 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326494 NEM:        Bit 06 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326497 NEM:        Bit 07 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326503 NEM:        Bit 08 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326506 NEM:        Bit 09 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326509 NEM:        Bit 10 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326513 NEM:        Bit 11 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326516 NEM:        Bit 12 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326519 NEM:        Bit 13 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326522 NEM:        Bit 14 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326525 NEM:        Bit 15 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326529 NEM:        Bit 16 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326553 NEM:        Bit 17 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326556 NEM:        Bit 18 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326559 NEM:        Bit 19 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326562 NEM:        Bit 20 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326565 NEM:        Bit 21 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326568 NEM:        Bit 22 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326571 NEM:        Bit 23 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326573 NEM:        Bit 24 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326576 NEM:        Bit 25 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326579 NEM:        Bit 26 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326582 NEM:        Bit 27 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326585 NEM:        Bit 28 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326588 NEM:        Bit 29 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326591 NEM:        Bit 30 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326594 NEM:        Bit 31 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326598 NEM:    VMX_VMCS32_CTRL_EXIT = (allowed_0=0x236fff allowed_1=0x737fff)
00:00:00.326601 NEM:        Bit 00 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326604 NEM:        Bit 01 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326607 NEM:        Bit 02 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326610 NEM:        Bit 03 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326613 NEM:        Bit 04 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326616 NEM:        Bit 05 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326619 NEM:        Bit 06 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326622 NEM:        Bit 07 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326625 NEM:        Bit 08 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326627 NEM:        Bit 09 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326630 NEM:        Bit 10 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326633 NEM:        Bit 11 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326636 NEM:        Bit 12 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326639 NEM:        Bit 13 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326642 NEM:        Bit 14 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326645 NEM:        Bit 15 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326648 NEM:        Bit 16 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326651 NEM:        Bit 17 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326654 NEM:        Bit 18 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326657 NEM:        Bit 19 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326660 NEM:        Bit 20 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326663 NEM:        Bit 21 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326666 NEM:        Bit 22 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326669 NEM:        Bit 23 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326672 NEM:        Bit 24 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326674 NEM:        Bit 25 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326677 NEM:        Bit 26 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326680 NEM:        Bit 27 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326683 NEM:        Bit 28 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326686 NEM:        Bit 29 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326689 NEM:        Bit 30 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326692 NEM:        Bit 31 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326695 NEM:    VMX_VMCS32_CTRL_ENTRY = (allowed_0=0x0091ff allowed_1=0x00b3ff)
00:00:00.326699 NEM:        Bit 00 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326702 NEM:        Bit 01 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326705 NEM:        Bit 02 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326708 NEM:        Bit 03 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326711 NEM:        Bit 04 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326714 NEM:        Bit 05 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326717 NEM:        Bit 06 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326720 NEM:        Bit 07 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326729 NEM:        Bit 08 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326732 NEM:        Bit 09 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326735 NEM:        Bit 10 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326738 NEM:        Bit 11 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326741 NEM:        Bit 12 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326744 NEM:        Bit 13 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326747 NEM:        Bit 14 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326750 NEM:        Bit 15 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326753 NEM:        Bit 16 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326755 NEM:        Bit 17 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326758 NEM:        Bit 18 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326761 NEM:        Bit 19 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326764 NEM:        Bit 20 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326767 NEM:        Bit 21 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326770 NEM:        Bit 22 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326773 NEM:        Bit 23 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326776 NEM:        Bit 24 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326779 NEM:        Bit 25 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326782 NEM:        Bit 26 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326784 NEM:        Bit 27 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326787 NEM:        Bit 28 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326790 NEM:        Bit 29 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326793 NEM:        Bit 30 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326796 NEM:        Bit 31 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326799 NEM:    VMX_VMCS32_CTRL_PROC_EXEC2 = (allowed_0=0x0000a2 allowed_1=0x515cef)
00:00:00.326803 NEM:        Bit 00 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326806 NEM:        Bit 01 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326809 NEM:        Bit 02 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326812 NEM:        Bit 03 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326815 NEM:        Bit 04 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326818 NEM:        Bit 05 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326820 NEM:        Bit 06 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326823 NEM:        Bit 07 = MUST be set
00:00:00.326826 NEM:        Bit 08 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326829 NEM:        Bit 09 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326832 NEM:        Bit 10 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326835 NEM:        Bit 11 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326838 NEM:        Bit 12 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326841 NEM:        Bit 13 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326844 NEM:        Bit 14 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326847 NEM:        Bit 15 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326850 NEM:        Bit 16 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326853 NEM:        Bit 17 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326856 NEM:        Bit 18 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326859 NEM:        Bit 19 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326862 NEM:        Bit 20 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326864 NEM:        Bit 21 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326867 NEM:        Bit 22 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326870 NEM:        Bit 23 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326873 NEM:        Bit 24 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326876 NEM:        Bit 25 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326879 NEM:        Bit 26 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326882 NEM:        Bit 27 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326885 NEM:        Bit 28 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326888 NEM:        Bit 29 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326891 NEM:        Bit 30 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326894 NEM:        Bit 31 = Must NOT be set
00:00:00.326897 NEM:    VMX_VMCS32_CTRL_PLE_GAP = (allowed_0=0x000000 allowed_1=0xffffffff)
00:00:00.326900 NEM:        Bit 00 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326903 NEM:        Bit 01 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326906 NEM:        Bit 02 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326909 NEM:        Bit 03 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326912 NEM:        Bit 04 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326915 NEM:        Bit 05 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326918 NEM:        Bit 06 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326921 NEM:        Bit 07 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326924 NEM:        Bit 08 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326927 NEM:        Bit 09 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326930 NEM:        Bit 10 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326932 NEM:        Bit 11 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326935 NEM:        Bit 12 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326938 NEM:        Bit 13 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326947 NEM:        Bit 14 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326950 NEM:        Bit 15 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326953 NEM:        Bit 16 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326956 NEM:        Bit 17 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326959 NEM:        Bit 18 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326962 NEM:        Bit 19 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326965 NEM:        Bit 20 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326968 NEM:        Bit 21 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326971 NEM:        Bit 22 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326974 NEM:        Bit 23 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326976 NEM:        Bit 24 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326979 NEM:        Bit 25 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326982 NEM:        Bit 26 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326985 NEM:        Bit 27 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326988 NEM:        Bit 28 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326991 NEM:        Bit 29 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326994 NEM:        Bit 30 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.326997 NEM:        Bit 31 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327000 NEM:    VMX_VMCS32_CTRL_PLE_WINDOW = (allowed_0=0x000000 allowed_1=0xffffffff)
00:00:00.327003 NEM:        Bit 00 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327006 NEM:        Bit 01 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327009 NEM:        Bit 02 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327012 NEM:        Bit 03 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327015 NEM:        Bit 04 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327018 NEM:        Bit 05 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327021 NEM:        Bit 06 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327024 NEM:        Bit 07 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327026 NEM:        Bit 08 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327029 NEM:        Bit 09 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327032 NEM:        Bit 10 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327035 NEM:        Bit 11 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327038 NEM:        Bit 12 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327041 NEM:        Bit 13 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327044 NEM:        Bit 14 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327047 NEM:        Bit 15 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327050 NEM:        Bit 16 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327053 NEM:        Bit 17 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327055 NEM:        Bit 18 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327058 NEM:        Bit 19 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327061 NEM:        Bit 20 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327064 NEM:        Bit 21 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327067 NEM:        Bit 22 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327070 NEM:        Bit 23 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327073 NEM:        Bit 24 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327076 NEM:        Bit 25 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327078 NEM:        Bit 26 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327081 NEM:        Bit 27 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327084 NEM:        Bit 28 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327087 NEM:        Bit 29 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327090 NEM:        Bit 30 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327093 NEM:        Bit 31 = Can be set or not be set
00:00:00.327096 NEM:    VMX_VMCS64_CTRL_TSC_OFFSET_FULL = (allowed_0=0xffffffffffffffff allowed_1=0x00000000000000)
00:00:00.327100 NEM:        Bit 00 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327103 NEM:        Bit 01 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327106 NEM:        Bit 02 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327109 NEM:        Bit 03 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327112 NEM:        Bit 04 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327115 NEM:        Bit 05 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327118 NEM:        Bit 06 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327121 NEM:        Bit 07 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327124 NEM:        Bit 08 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327127 NEM:        Bit 09 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327129 NEM:        Bit 10 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327132 NEM:        Bit 11 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327141 NEM:        Bit 12 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327145 NEM:        Bit 13 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327148 NEM:        Bit 14 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327150 NEM:        Bit 15 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327153 NEM:        Bit 16 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327156 NEM:        Bit 17 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327159 NEM:        Bit 18 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327162 NEM:        Bit 19 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327165 NEM:        Bit 20 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327168 NEM:        Bit 21 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327171 NEM:        Bit 22 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327174 NEM:        Bit 23 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327177 NEM:        Bit 24 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327180 NEM:        Bit 25 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327183 NEM:        Bit 26 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327185 NEM:        Bit 27 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327188 NEM:        Bit 28 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327191 NEM:        Bit 29 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327194 NEM:        Bit 30 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327197 NEM:        Bit 31 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327200 NEM:        Bit 32 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327203 NEM:        Bit 33 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327206 NEM:        Bit 34 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327209 NEM:        Bit 35 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327212 NEM:        Bit 36 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327215 NEM:        Bit 37 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327217 NEM:        Bit 38 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327220 NEM:        Bit 39 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327223 NEM:        Bit 40 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327226 NEM:        Bit 41 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327229 NEM:        Bit 42 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327232 NEM:        Bit 43 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327235 NEM:        Bit 44 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327238 NEM:        Bit 45 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327241 NEM:        Bit 46 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327244 NEM:        Bit 47 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327246 NEM:        Bit 48 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327249 NEM:        Bit 49 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327252 NEM:        Bit 50 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327255 NEM:        Bit 51 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327258 NEM:        Bit 52 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327261 NEM:        Bit 53 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327264 NEM:        Bit 54 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327267 NEM:        Bit 55 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327270 NEM:        Bit 56 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327273 NEM:        Bit 57 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327276 NEM:        Bit 58 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327278 NEM:        Bit 59 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327281 NEM:        Bit 60 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327284 NEM:        Bit 61 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327287 NEM:        Bit 62 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327290 NEM:        Bit 63 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327293 NEM:    VMX_VMCS64_GUEST_DEBUGCTL_FULL = (allowed_0=0xffffffffffffffff allowed_1=0x00000000009803)
00:00:00.327297 NEM:        Bit 00 = MUST be set
00:00:00.327300 NEM:        Bit 01 = MUST be set
00:00:00.327303 NEM:        Bit 02 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327306 NEM:        Bit 03 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327309 NEM:        Bit 04 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327312 NEM:        Bit 05 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327315 NEM:        Bit 06 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327318 NEM:        Bit 07 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327320 NEM:        Bit 08 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327323 NEM:        Bit 09 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327326 NEM:        Bit 10 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327335 NEM:        Bit 11 = MUST be set
00:00:00.327338 NEM:        Bit 12 = MUST be set
00:00:00.327341 NEM:        Bit 13 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327344 NEM:        Bit 14 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327347 NEM:        Bit 15 = MUST be set
00:00:00.327350 NEM:        Bit 16 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327353 NEM:        Bit 17 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327356 NEM:        Bit 18 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327359 NEM:        Bit 19 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327362 NEM:        Bit 20 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327365 NEM:        Bit 21 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327368 NEM:        Bit 22 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327371 NEM:        Bit 23 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327373 NEM:        Bit 24 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327376 NEM:        Bit 25 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327379 NEM:        Bit 26 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327382 NEM:        Bit 27 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327385 NEM:        Bit 28 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327388 NEM:        Bit 29 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327391 NEM:        Bit 30 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327394 NEM:        Bit 31 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327397 NEM:        Bit 32 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327400 NEM:        Bit 33 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327403 NEM:        Bit 34 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327406 NEM:        Bit 35 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327409 NEM:        Bit 36 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327411 NEM:        Bit 37 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327414 NEM:        Bit 38 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327417 NEM:        Bit 39 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327420 NEM:        Bit 40 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327423 NEM:        Bit 41 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327426 NEM:        Bit 42 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327429 NEM:        Bit 43 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327432 NEM:        Bit 44 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
00:00:00.327435 NEM:        Bit 45 = UNDEFINED (AppleHV error)!
```

My OS is:

```
ProductName:            macOS
ProductVersion:         13.5.2
BuildVersion:           22G91
```

The CPU of course supports virtualization:

```
sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features
machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 PCLMULQDQ DTES64 MON DSCPL VMX SMX EST TM2 SSSE3 FMA CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1 SSE4.2 x2APIC MOVBE POPCNT AES PCID XSAVE OSXSAVE SEGLIM64 TSCTMR AVX1.0 RDRAND F16C
```

Virtualization is of course enabled in the machine (`showvminfo`):

```
Hardware Virtualization:     enabled
Nested Paging:               enabled
Large Pages:                 enabled
VT-x VPID:                   enabled
VT-x Unrestricted Exec.:     enabled
AMD-V Virt. Vmsave/Vmload:   enabled
IOMMU:                       None
Paravirt. Provider:          Default
Effective Paravirt. Prov.:   None
```

How can I fix/enable hardware virtualization on my Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you installed the [VirtualBox 7.0.12 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) on the Ventura host and Guest Additions CD on the Windows XP guest.

According to [Oracle](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/UserManual.pdf), macOS Ventura is not supported as a host OS when using VirtualBox 7.0.12. [Ventura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Timeline_of_releases) was released October 24, 2022 and [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) 7.0.12 was released October 17, 2023.

You might consider trying the current [VMware Fusion Player 13](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/13/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-84E34BF1-92A2-4B86-9995-70893A9B04A9.html), which supports *"any Mac that officially supports macOS 12 Monterey or later*". WMware offers a free [VMware Fusion Player – Personal Use License](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/en/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal-13).

You can have the VirtualBox and Fusion Player installed on your Mac at the same time.